# highlight a portion of an xml in different color that matches a list of xpath expression, how to do it in xslt

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath

Have a list of xpath expression as input and an xml file, I have to highlight the portion of the xml that matched the xpath expression.

Given below a list of xpath expressions which is an output from a java program

```
/myroot[1]/mychild[1]/test[1]/@testing
/myroot[1]/mychild[2]/comment[1]
/myroot[1]/mychild[3]/dates[1]/created[1]/text()[1]
/myroot[1]/mychild[3]/dates[1]/accessed[1]/text()[1]
```

Also given below the xml file

```
    <myroot >
        <mychild id="123">
            <fruit>apple</fruit>
            <test hello="world" testing="removed" brackets="angled" question="answers"/>
            <comment>This is a comment</comment>
        </mychild>

        <mychild id="789">

            <fruit>orange</fruit>
            <test brackets="round" hello="greeting">
                <number>111</number>
            </test>
            <!-- this is a test comment

           -->
            <dates>
                  <modified>123</modified>
                  <created>880</created>
                  <accessed>44</accessed>
            </dates>
        </mychild>


        <mychild id="456">
            <fruit>banana</fruit>
            <comment>This will be removed</comment>
        </mychild>
    </myroot>
```

Now I need to prepare an html output that highlights the portion of the xml that matched all the xpath expressions.

I would like to highlight the portion of the xml that matches the xpath expressions in different color. Is it easier to attempt this using CSS or is it possible to do this using XSLT

In the sample xml i have given the text to be highlighted inside ** assume it will be shown as bolded text.

Sample output html given below

```
    <myroot >
        <mychild id="123">
            <fruit>apple</fruit>
            <test hello="world" <div> testing="removed" </div>  brackets="angled" question="answers"/>
            <comment>This is a comment</comment>
        </mychild>

        <mychild id="789">

            <fruit>orange</fruit>
            <test brackets="round" hello="greeting">
                <number>111</number>
            </test><div>
            <!-- this is a test comment

           --></div>
            <dates>
                  <modified>123</modified>
                  <created><div>880</div></created>
                  <accessed><div>44</div></accessed>
            </dates>
        </mychild>


        <mychild id="456">
            <fruit>banana</fruit>
            <comment>This will be removed</comment>
        </mychild>
    </myroot>
```

Comment: xml has no concept of colours, from your question it seems like you might be talking about html output. So you probably have a stylesheet converting the xml to the html and want to modify that to add colouring on top? It might be helpful if you show what you have.

Comment: **1.** Please post the expected HTML output of the transformation. **2.** Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Note added a sample output xml with extra div tag for the text that matches the xpath expression,   using XSLT 2.0 is ok.

Comment: The output is invalid: you cannot have a `div` within an attribute. -- When you say XSLT 2.0, do you mean Saxon? You will need an extension function to evaluate a string as XPath.

Comment: @michael.hor257k is there a better way to highlight only one attribute in different color  in an xml file  that will be displayed as html

Comment: @user3626733 i'm trying to find a solution for this exact requirement, please share your solution if possible . Thank you